# How can I check each 3 elements of a singly linked list and then delete some of them?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So basically I have this assignment on my University that asks to make a sorted singly linked list and then make some methods on it. The one that I'm having trouble is: "create delete() function that checks the average of each triple elements and if it's lower than integer 'K' (which is a parameter of said function) deletes the first element of the triple or deletes second and last element of the triple if it's higher."

I already made a function/method that deletes a single element of the linked list.

```cpp
void LinkedList::deleteElement(int a)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    Node *previousTemp = head;

    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        if(temp->value == a)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            previousTemp = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    if(temp == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Can't delete. Element not found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nDeleting element: " << temp->value << endl;
        previousTemp->next = temp->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    howMany--;
}

void Sznur::deleteTriple()
{
    Node *first = head;
    Node *second = first->next;
    Node *third = second->next;

}
```

The task is written pretty hard to understand but for ex.:

```
int K=3
linkedList: 7,6,6,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1
```

after running the function:

```
linkedList: 7,3,1,1,1,1
```

(7+6+6)/3 > K -> deletes 6 and 6

(3+3+3)/3 > K -> deltes second 3 and last 3

(2+1+1)/3 < K -> deletes 2

If the linkedList length is not dividable by 3 the last elements stay in their place.

Comment: Where do you use `deleteTriple` function? It doesn't seem to delete anything.

Comment: Well it's only linkedList.cpp. I have another cpp file in which I run everything.

Comment: the ```deleteElement``` is meant to delete single element and I want to use it to help me delete the triple

Comment: To put it another way: I don't know how to iterate through the first 3 elements than another 3 elements and another 3 elements. I will figure something out when I do it

Comment: Can you explain why in the case of `3 3 3` it would delete the second and third elements if `K = 3`?  From your problem description I would expect nothing to be deleted.  If `avg > K` delete second and third, if `avg < K` delete first.  In this case you have `avg == K` so it is neither greater nor less than `K`.

Comment: @pstrjds hmm... The tutor that made this task didn't specify what to do in that case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
void tripleFunc(Node* head, int K)
{
    Node* nodePtr = head; // nodePtr always points at the start of a new triple
    while (true)
    {
        Node* first = nullptr;
        Node* second = nullptr;
        Node* third = nullptr;

        first = nodePtr; // When taking the three elements out, remember to always check for a null pointer BEFORE accessing the element
        if (first)
            second = first->next;
        if (second)
            third = second->next;
        if (third)
            nodePtr = third->next; // Keep the nodePtr pointing at the start of the next triple
        else
            return; // Only happens if one or more of the previous ifs failed, which means that we don't have enough elements left for a full triple

        if (calculateAverage(first, second, third) < K) // Make this function
        {
            deleteElement(first->value);
        }
        else
        {
            deleteElement(second->value);
            deleteElement(third->value);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it though, so any possible bugs are left as an exercise to the reader to find and sort out. :)

Comment: Instead of `while(true)` I think it would be cleaner to have `while (nodePtr)` or for clarity `while (nodePtr != nullptr)`.

Comment: Also just noticed that you seem to be calling the `deleteElement`  `deleteElement` method as shown in OPs question, but it would be incorrect to use that in this case as 1 - it requires traversing the list a second time, which is unecessary, and 2 it starts from the top and removes the first matching value element, which may or may not be the one you think you are deleting.  Using OPs example of `7,6,6,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1`, and the case of `3,3,3` where you are supposed to delete the second and third `3`, if you call `deleteElement` you will delete the first and second instead of second and third.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it a slight bit and that answer fixes my problem. @pstrjds - It doesn't work exactly as I wanted it to but the end result after running the function is good enough for this task.